# Time based workflow email notification not working

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I've scenario where I need to send email notification when case record is in status 'Open' for more than 7 days. The time based workflow information are as follows
Evaluation Criteria: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria

Rule Criteria:  Case 'Status' = "Open" and Send Notification (Custom field) = TRUE

Time-Dependant Workflow action: 7 days after Case: Date/Time Opened (standard field)
Email Recipient: Case owner
We've two sandbox, one for development and the other for testing. The email notification works perfectly in development sandbox. But it doesn't works in testing sandbox.
I checked the time based workflow queue. The triggered workflow action is available in queue, but the mail is not being delivered.
The deliverability access level is 'All Emails'. 
I did the test deliverability and it sends test mail.
Can anyone please advise me the possible reasons for not sending mails for this time based workflow?

Comment: Check weather the workflow rule is active or not in the Test sandbox.

Comment: @Suri, the workflow rule is active and the time-dependent actions is queued when the criteria is met.